# Flutter track or detect control/notification center screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to know when user is going into control center.

```
@override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    }

    @override
    dispose() {
        super.dispose();
        WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    }

    @override
    void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
        super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
        if(state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {


        } else if(state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {

        }
    }
```

With this widgetbindings it is unfortunately not possible to detect it. Do you guys have another idea to track it actually?

Answer (score 0):

With Flutter v3.13.8, u can detect it inside `AppLifecycleState.inactive`